# Service not found in container while setup for SECOND test (first is working)

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have wrote a testcase with a longer setUp which looks something like this:

```
public function setUp(){

        $this->manager = $this->get('strego_tipp.invalidation_manager');

        $mockEm = m::mock('Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager');
        $this->setAttribute($this->manager, 'em', $mockEm);

        /* .... additional setup stuff ....*/

}


protected function get($service){
        return $this->getContainer()->get($service);
}
```

This is just the setup, and now I have 2 tests in my testfile:

```
public function test_it_collects_not_duplicate_betRounds(){
        $this->assertCount(0, $this->manager->betRounds);
        $this->call($this->manager,'collectBetRoundWorkload', $this->game1);
        $this->call($this->manager,'collectBetRoundWorkload', $this->game2);
        $this->manager->collectBetRoundWorkload($this->game1);
        $this->manager->collectBetRoundWorkload($this->game2);
        $this->assertCount(2, $this->manager->betRounds);

    }

    public function test_it_collects_all_bets_to_update(){
        $this->assertCount(0, $this->manager->bets);
        $this->call($this->manager,'collectBetWorkload', $this->game1);
        $this->manager->collectBetWorkload($this->game1);
        $this->assertCount(3, $this->manager->bets);   
    }
```

When running the test, the second testcase always fails because within the setup there is no service named 'strego_tipp.invalidation_manager' in the container. Although the service was available in the first test. It is also independent from the actual testcase because I can change the order of the tests and still the service is not in the container for the second testcase.  This seems to me like a very random problem and I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by cleaning cache because I was on prod environment:

```
$app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Hope it helps :)